# Inserting images in drupal 7 pages

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have created drop down menu, but it is not showing in home page where as it is working on cities(my website page) page
and
I have inserted a image as directed here : http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/image

But i am not getting it. Can you please check it once?

http://netelity.com/drupal

Please someone help me in this.

Comment: Are you using drupals menu system for the top navigation? If you are, list links and tick expanded on the cities link then save.

Comment: Hi Ben, Sorry i did not get what i should do. Can you please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu system show only the current trail so cities submenu will be visible only on the cities pages.

Try selecting "always expanded" in the menu items configuration page (build > menu > your-menu) as Ben Swinburne suggested

or use something like this in page.tpl.php (or better in a hook in template.php)

```
 <?
  $tree = menu_tree_page_data("your-menu", 0, false);
  echo menu_tree_output($tree);
?>
```

this should show you all the submenu items for each parent menu item.
for reference see

- http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_tree_page_data/7
- http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--menu.inc/function/menu_tree/7